# Modifying search results based on post_type

Tags: custom-post-types, filters, search

Is there an easy way to highlight search results based on post_type?

I am using Job Manager plugin and when a site search is performed, I want to simply add a note e.g. (Job) next to the Job Results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you can PHP it using an if statement.. like so:

**Say this is the loop.. (simple one i know):**

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php 
    $post_type = get_post_type_object( get_post_type($post) );
    $post_type_name = $post_type->labels->singular_name

    if ($post_type_name == 'example') {
    echo '<div class="highlight searchResults">';
    } else {
    echo '<div>';
?>

<h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
<p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
</div>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

.
Dont forget to change the 'example' with the singular name of the custom post type you are checking for in the search restuls...

Hope this helps :)